# HttpApplicationState not available in an MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, controller, global-variables, global-asax

I'm using MVC2 and VS2010 developing a website and need to use Application State global values. I can set a value like 'Application["hits"]=0;' in Global.asax but when trying to use the same in an MVC controller always get the following error:

The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context

I have also tried using  in the Global.asax in order to define a global variable but it triggers the following error:

A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

I'm looking for a way to define global Application State values that are available within all controllers of my MVC2 web application. Am I omitting something? My controller looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCApplication.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Application["hits"] += 1;

            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

I appreciate any solutions and/or suggestions.

Thanks
Mehrdad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266533/does-asp-net-mvc-have-application-variables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I *think* that in MVC3 you can get access to an actual HttpApplicationState object via the

```
HttpContext.ApplicationInstance
```

property. That is:

```
HttpApplicationState application = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Application
```

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET MVC2, i use

```
HttpContext.Application["foo"] = "bar";
```

and to get

```
HttpContext.Application["foo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static class with an internal dictionary and an indexer.

Also, have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Application`?

Comment: Thanks Jaroslav, the problem is now solved using the following in the controllers:

HttpContext.Application["hits"]