# What is the equivalent of Page.Application (in .aspx.cs page) In MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, application-variables

I am working on MVC web application, and I am using `.Dlls`. of some other project. That same .dll is also using in  my another Web Application which is made in WebForms (.aspx) pages.

**Now my question is:** some function from that .dll are accepting  `Page.Application` as a parameter. Which is working fine in .aspx page. BUT now I want to use same function in MVC application. But in `MVC controller` I am not able to access that `Page.Application`

So Please someone can help me That How can I access `Page.Application` in MVC Controller and Is there any equivalent of `Page.Application` in MVC Controller

Thanks,

**EDIT:-**
 I am not asking about `Application variable` - I am asking about `Page.Application` which is object of `HttpApplicationState` . I want this `HttpApplicationState` in MVC Controller

Comment: You can access `Application` variables from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application` since MVC controller classes not derived from `System.Web.UI.Page` unlike webforms classes have.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - it is not about `Application variable` - `Page.Application` is object of `HttpApplicationState` . I want this `HttpApplicationState` in MVC Controller

Comment: There is no application state in ASP.NET MVC. The DLL you're using in webform is not applicable , you should use viewbag or viewdata since MVC is stateless unlike webforms which is managed by viewstate.

Comment: You can create similar property on model class which derives `HttpApplicationState` class e.g.: `public static HttpApplicationState Application { get { return HttpContext.Current.Application; }}`. Note that `Session` and `ViewBag/ViewData` approach is more preferred ahead of application variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mvc, there is no page lifecycle as in webform. Every thing from routing machanism.

While page.application, it is gets the HttpApplicationState object for the current Web request.

From MVC3 it support **HttpApplicationState** variable in mvc.

Check this answer :

[HttpApplicationState not available in an MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213581/httpapplicationstate-not-available-in-an-mvc-controller)

[Does asp.net MVC have Application variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266533/does-asp-net-mvc-have-application-variables)

Comment: Perfect - link has the answer - 
HttpApplicationState application = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Application

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
HttpContext.Application
```

and You have to add :

```
using System.Web;
```