# How can I use the same instance of a non-static class in every controller in an ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to the ASP.Net framework, and I am currently struggling to understand how to manage lifetimes of objects.

In a more specific case I am currently facing a problem in my application:

I want to have a class starting with my application, which should run in the background and do some work which results in some data my application controllers are working with later on.

I would therefore try to create this class' object in my `Global.asax.cs`, so it can start and run as soon as my application is running as well.

However, how can I pass this instance to controllers which might get called later on then?

Currently, my only idea would be to make my data-collection class `static`, which I am not really happy with, as I would like to avoid static classes as much as possible.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Maybe you could use Singleton:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: Configure your controllers for dependency injection, then register your instance as a singleton with your DI container. This will permit much greater flexibility in the future, as all your controllers know about is a class (or, preferably, an interface) that they get supplied with in their constructor.

Comment: @RB. Thank you! I heard about Ninject already, I think I will take a look at this

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I would call this a red flag. If you have a [crosscutting concern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658105.aspx), the ideal place to put it in ASP.NET MVC is in a globally registered [filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) so you don't have to do something in every controller. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36224308).

Comment: BTW - the asp.net tag is general and does not imply which UI framework you are using. Please specify the UI framework you are using (asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, webforms, etc).

Comment: The state of the art pattern for this sort of thing is to use Dependency Injection and specify instance per process.  You might want to look at [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/285339/share-service-instances-amongst-all-controllers). DI may not be available without a third party package like [AutoFac](https://autofac.org/) (depending on your version of MVC).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class with static members or alternatively a singleton to hold data and logic in one place. The processing inside the class could be started by a call to one of its methods in `Global.asax.cs` in `Application_Start`.

Since more than one thread may access static data collection simultaneously, the data collection may require multi-thread access handling.

Answer (score 1):

Options from top of my head:

- [Application Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266533/does-asp-net-mvc-have-application-variables) `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["Name"] = "Value";`
  You can add your whole object in the application variable and will be able to access the same object everywhere in your application life time.
- Singleton which still a static way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx
- Using a static variable

Comment: Thanks, these are some good suggestions. I am having trouble fitting my knowledge about usual C# programming in the whole lifecycle of ASP.Net applications. The application variable route seems great.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a dependency injection framework such as Autofac, you could instantiate a new instance of your class and register it as a single instance (singleton) with the DI framework.

```
// In your DI config -- Autofac used here as an example
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
myFoo.Start();
builder.RegisterInstance<Foo>(myFoo).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
```

Then, just add it as an argument to the constructor of your controllers.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly Foo _myFoo;

    public HomeController(Foo myFoo)
    {
        _myFoo = myFoo;
    }
}
```