# what is application variable? How do i declare Application variables in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, variables

Where to declare(Application variable) and How to access application variable in controller ?
How to get model(model.tt file) value from database in application_start() ? 
i don't have any idea about application variable, So if you know anything about it then help me.
Thanks..!

Comment: no , in this question there is no any answer like where to declare or how  to access in controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does asp.net MVC have Application variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266533/does-asp-net-mvc-have-application-variables)

Comment: how could you suggest this isn't a duplicate?  Is this not the exact answer you are looking for?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42222894/2495283

Comment: but, it won't work.i already do it.

Comment: is there any alternate way , then suggest me.

Comment: If it does not work please show us your code so we can see and verify it

Comment: Company won't give permission to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **global.asax** file
first declare service in which you write linq syntax or your logic,

```
 private readonly ISystemConfigurationService _systemConfigurationService;
```

Then, create constructor

```
public MvcApplication()
    {
        _systemConfigurationService = new SystemConfigurationService();
    }
```

Get Model Data when app start

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        List<SystemConfigurationModel> systemConfigurationValue = General.MapList<System_Configuration , SystemConfigurationModel> (_systemConfigurationService.GetAllSystemConfigData());
        Application["SystemConfig"] = new List<SystemConfigurationModel>(systemConfigurationValue);
    }
```

In **controller** you have to do this,

```
List<SystemConfigurationModel> applicationState = HttpContext.Application["SystemConfig"] as List<SystemConfigurationModel>;
ViewBag.ContactEmail = applicationState.Find(x => x.Config_Key == "ContactMail").Value;
```

Then Pass it to view using view bag.